# $ is not a function in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make a site responsive but I need to reorder the sidebars to make them appear below the content.
I found this script in another answer but it tells me $ is not a function in the console. I guess this is something about jquery and how wordpress handles it with document ready and that kind of thing, but I don't know how the syntax is and stuff..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function() {
if ( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
    $("#firstsidebar").insertAfter("#maincontent");
}
else{
    $("#maincontent").insertAfter("#firstsidebar");
}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
    $("#firstsidebar").insertAfter("#maincontent");
}
});
</script>
```

EDIT.
ok. I am getting a lot of negative ratings because of this question. Maybe it is super simple and stupid, but I don't know javascript and jquery, I just "kind of" understand it a little.

Comment: try ``jQuery`` instead of ``$``

Comment: WP might be calling noConflict... use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: I usually pass in $ to my .ready() so that I can use the alias.

Comment: Do I need to replace jQuery in every $ or just in the first one? :( *blushes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jQuery doesn't respond to `$`, it's usually either because there's a conflict with another library trying to use the same [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)), or the CMS / Web server / environment is set up to explicitly avoid such conflicts.

You can use `jQuery` every place you would normally use `$`. That almost invariably works.

Or you can wrap the invocation in a function that establishes a local argument:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
    $( "div" ).hide();
});
```

Other options are available, including defining your own custom access point (like `jq` or `J$`), or even defining the `$` to explicitly point to `jQuery` (or the `jQuery.noConflict()` proxy). Many of these are [discussed in the jQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/).

You can also brute-force it, by defining `$` early on in your code:

```
$ = jQuery;
```

Now `$` will work exactly as you expected. Probably. (Unless or until it doesn't, because one of the aforementioned JS library compatibility issues has bitten you. At which point you might decide to fall back to one of the more structured, planned ways of achieving compatibility.)

Answer (score 2):

WordPress uses jQuery in "no conflict" mode, which means that by default you cannot use $.  The reason for this is that other javascript libraries also use $.

To get around this you can either replace each instance of $ with jQuery, or you can wrap the code in something like this::

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

});
```